# Logback: "Could not find Janino library on the class path"

Tags: logback, janino

I'm getting error message `Could not find Janino library on the class path. Skipping conditional processing.` What should I incude in classpath to fix this (lib and version)?

Comment: There is a Janino entry in the FAQ: http://logback.qos.ch/setup.html#janino

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Logback [requires the Janino library](http://logback.qos.ch/setup.html#janino) for conditional logging. You don't need it if you aren't using the  structures in your config files.

If you are using conditionals, you will need to add the Janino dependency. You can add this to your pom.xml file to get the dependency:

```
    <!-- The org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:2.6.1 dependency -->
    <!-- will be automatically pulled in by Maven's transitivity rules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I believe this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017148/logback-conditional-logging).

Comment: Whole addition of dependencies can be misleading and is usually considered a bad idea. I would remove everything after "For for a more complete dependency list, try.." in the above answer.

Comment: Worked for me as I accidently missed it out in gradle.