# Can't read one variable in logback.xml but can read another

Tags: java, environment-variables, redhat, logback, splunk

I am trying to read env variable in `logback.xml` file.
I can do:

```
<variable name="JAVA" value="${JAVA_HOME}" />
```

and the use it later:

```
<source>MY APP ${JAVA}</source>
```

and it works however when I created new variable by `setenv ENV TEST` (it's Red Hat) and I check if it's in environment variables by `printenv` then I can see it `ENV=TEST`. When I try to define it in `logback.xml` the same way as `JAVA_HOME` so: `<variable name="ENVIRONMENT" value="${ENV}" />` and use here:

```
<source>MY APP ${ENVIRONMENT}</source>
```

then I can see in SPLUNK: `source = MY APP ENV_IS_UNDEFINED`

Or is there another way to put `ENVIRONMENT` value somewhere and then read `ENVIRONMENT` in `logback.xml`?

I found: [if condition in logback - print log messages in two different folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715211/if-condition-in-logback-print-log-messages-in-two-different-folders) but my problem is different

@Edit

Even though I am starting process with:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java \
    -Duser.timezone=GMT \
    -Denv="test" \
    -Dhost="127.0.0.1" \
    ...
```

and trying to send it to SPLUNK by `<source>MY APP ${env}</source>` I can see in SPLNUK UI `source = MY APP env_IS_UNDEFINED`

When I run service locally with: [image: VM options] then it works locally

Comment: VM options aren’t env variables. There’s a separate place for those in IntelliJ. Are you saying you can export it to Splunk from local?

Comment: in `logback.xml` both are checked (env variables at the end if I recall, JVM options before). Yes, when I put into configuration in IntelliJ into `VM options` `env` and `hostname` then it's exported to SPLUNK and I can see it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<source>${env}</source>
```

is perfectly fine, there was discrepancy between start scripts which I was using.

To conclude:
If you use `${variable}` and in start script you use `-Dvariable = something` then it works.